# Return an array from shell script to iterate/process in shell command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that makes a list of calls to APIs and collects the response Codes into an array called `updateResponses`. I looked many placed and `declare -p` was recommended, but it's not working the way it's described or maybe I am using it wrong.

**What I need** : return the Array from the script and verify the elements by iterating over them.

My `script.sh` contains the highlights for this action:

```
   updateResponses=()
   do
    ..get statusCodes from list of calls in a loop...
     updateResponses+=("$statusCode")
   done
declare -p updateResponses
```

in my terminal after I execute this script, I see the array printed out but it is not an array to iterate over although it looks as if it was re-initialized to be used. Running `echo "${#updateResponses[@]}"` returns 0 as the size.

Example of the output after `script.sh` is done running :

```
declare -a updateResponses='([0]="200" [1]="200" [2]="200" [3]="200" [4]="200" [5]="200" [6]="200" [7]="200" [8]="200" [9]="200" [10]="200" [11]="200" [12]="200" [13]="200" [14]="200" [15]="200" [16]="200" [17]="200" [18]="200" [19]="200" [20]="200" [21]="200" [22]="200" [23]="200" [24]="200" [25]="200" [26]="200" [27]="200" [28]="200" [29]="200" [30]="200" [31]="200" [32]="200" [33]="200")'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the output of the script in the context of the current shell, e.g.

```
$ . <(arr=('a b' 'c d' 'e;f') ; declare -p arr)
$ echo ${arr[1]}
c d
```

Comment: thank you. Since my array is populated in script, I added this `. <(declare -p updateResponses)` at the end of the script. I am getting these errors in shell that script is ran in :                                                                              `script.sh: line 59: syntax error near unexpected token `('`
`script.sh: line 59: `. <(declare -p updateResponses)'`

Comment: @OjenG.: Sounds like you're not running `bash`.

Comment: My `.sh` file is staring with `#!/bin/bash` so it should be interpreted as bash, correct?

Comment: @OjenG.: How do you run it?

Comment: @OjenG.: Try `bash script.sh` instead, or just `./script.sh` to use what the shebang line says.

Comment: `bash script.sh` will run the script ok. Doesn't complain about syntax anymore, however it doesn't look like the array carried over to the shell (`"${#updateResponses[@]}"` returns `0` as the size). I also found a command that shows the variables + user defined variables in shell and it's not listed under there. The command is : `compgen -v`

Comment: @OjenG.: Scripts run in a subshell. You can't change the parent shell's environment from a child process. But you can try sourcing the script, if your parent shell is bash.